# Union / Union All makes query Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, union

I want to optimize this query to fetch data with in 1 seconds . currently its taking 4 - 6 seconds with union.With Union ALL its takes about 4 seconds & with Union It takes about 6 seconds to fetch data. Please help me to make a faster query .Here is my query below:

```
 SELECT  smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
          ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[Order]
          ,[ExamDate]
          ,[ArrivalTime]
          ,[Activity]
          ,[PatientFirstName]
          ,[PatientMiddleName]
          ,[PatientLastName]
          ,[DOB]
          ,[Order]
          ,[ActualExamTimeIn]
          ,[ActualExamTimeOut]
          ,[ActualScannerID]
          ,[ActualExamDate]
          ,[ActualCustomer]
          ,[ActualPatientFirstName]
          ,[ActualPatientLastName]
          ,[ActualDOB]
          ,[InsuranceCoID]
          ,[InsuranceID]
          ,[StartedInPreAuth]
          ,[DateReceived]
          ,[TimeReceived]
          ,[FDGPatientOrder]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[StatusID] AS PatientorderStatusID
          ,smsFDGOrder.[StatusID] AS FDGorderStatusID
          --,smsFDGPatientOrder.[TimeAdded]
          ,smsFDGOrder.[TimeAdded]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[Notes]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[cntID]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[empID]
          ,[Isotope]
          ,[Weight]
          ,[Diabetic]
          ,[Indication]
          ,[Procedure]
          ,[Physician]
          ,[InjectionTime]
          ,smsCustomers.custID
          ,effectChildren
    FROM VW_PatientOrderByMaxTimeAddedProc smsFDGPatientOrder 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[VW_FGDOrderByMaxTimeAddedProc] AS smsFDGOrder ON smsFDGPatientOrder.[Order]=smsFDGOrder.ID  
    LEFT JOIN smscustomers ON smsFDGOrder.Customer=smscustomers.custID WHERE
    (
     smsFDGPatientOrder.StatusID IN (2,5,13,14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23,8,25,39)
    AND
    smsFDGOrder.StatusID  IN(8,12,23,25)
    )
    UNION ALL
    (

      SELECT 
          smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
          ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[Order]
          ,[ExamDate]
          ,[ArrivalTime]
          ,[Activity]
          ,[PatientFirstName]
          ,[PatientMiddleName]
          ,[PatientLastName]
          ,[DOB]
          ,[Order]
          ,[ActualExamTimeIn]
          ,[ActualExamTimeOut]
          ,[ActualScannerID]
          ,[ActualExamDate]
          ,[ActualCustomer]
          ,[ActualPatientFirstName]
          ,[ActualPatientLastName]
          ,[ActualDOB]
          ,[InsuranceCoID]
          ,[InsuranceID]
          ,[StartedInPreAuth]
          ,[DateReceived]
          ,[TimeReceived]
          ,[FDGPatientOrder]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[StatusID] AS PatientorderStatusID
          ,smsFDGOrder.[StatusID] AS FDGorderStatusID
          --,smsFDGPatientOrder.[TimeAdded]
          ,smsFDGOrder.[TimeAdded]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[Notes]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[cntID]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[empID]
          ,[Isotope]
          ,[Weight]
          ,[Diabetic]
          ,[Indication]
          ,[Procedure]
          ,[Physician]
          ,[InjectionTime]
          ,smsCustomers.custID
          ,effectChildren
    FROM VW_PatientOrderByMaxTimeAddedProc smsFDGPatientOrder 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[VW_FGDOrderByMaxTimeAddedProc] AS smsFDGOrder ON smsFDGPatientOrder.[Order]=smsFDGOrder.ID  
    LEFT JOIN smscustomers ON smsFDGOrder.Customer=smscustomers.custID WHERE [order] IN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT [order] FROM  VW_PatientOrderByMaxTimeAddedProc smsFDGPatientOrder INNER JOIN [dbo].[VW_FGDOrderByMaxTimeAddedProc] AS smsFDGOrder ON smsFDGPatientOrder.[Order]=smsFDGOrder.ID WHERE smsFDGPatientOrder.StatusID IN(3) AND smsFDGOrder.StatusID IN (8,12)
    EXCEPT
    SELECT DISTINCT [order] FROM  VW_PatientOrderByMaxTimeAddedProc smsFDGPatientOrder INNER JOIN [dbo].[VW_FGDOrderByMaxTimeAddedProc] AS smsFDGOrder ON smsFDGPatientOrder.[Order]=smsFDGOrder.ID WHERE smsFDGPatientOrder.StatusID  IN(select id FROM smsStatus WHERE ID<>3) AND smsFDGOrder.StatusID IN (8,12)
    )

    ) 

    UNION 

    SELECT 
    smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
    ,smsFDGPatientOrder.[Order]
          ,[ExamDate]
          ,[ArrivalTime]
          ,[Activity]
          ,[PatientFirstName]
          ,[PatientMiddleName]
          ,[PatientLastName]
          ,[DOB]
          ,[Order]
          ,[ActualExamTimeIn]
          ,[ActualExamTimeOut]
          ,[ActualScannerID]
          ,[ActualExamDate]
          ,[ActualCustomer]
          ,[ActualPatientFirstName]
          ,[ActualPatientLastName]
          ,[ActualDOB]
          ,[InsuranceCoID]
          ,[InsuranceID]
          ,[StartedInPreAuth]
          ,[DateReceived]
          ,[TimeReceived]
          ,[FDGPatientOrder]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrderStatus.[StatusID] AS PatientorderStatusID
          ,smsFDGOrder.[StatusID] AS FDGorderStatusID
          ,smsFDGPatientOrderStatus.[TimeAdded]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrderStatus.[Notes]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrderStatus.[cntID]
          ,smsFDGPatientOrderStatus.[empID]
          ,[Isotope]
          ,[Weight]
          ,[Diabetic]
          ,[Indication]
          ,[Procedure]
          ,[Physician]
          ,[InjectionTime]
          ,smsCustomers.custID
          ,effectChildren
      FROM smsFDGPatientOrder LEFT JOIN smsFDGPatientOrderStatus ON smsFDGPatientOrder.ID= smsFDGPatientOrderStatus.FDGPatientOrder 
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[VW_FGDOrderByMaxTimeAddedProc] smsFDGOrder ON smsFDGPatientOrder.[Order]=smsFDGOrder.ID LEFT JOIN smscustomers ON smsFDGOrder.Customer=smscustomers.custID 
     WHERE smsFDGPatientOrderStatus.StatusID IS NULL AND  FDGPatientOrder IS NULL  AND smsFDGOrder.StatusID IN (8,12)  AND effectChildren=1 order by ID asc
```

Comment: Consistently use `UNION ALL` or `UNION`.  For performance, use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: You Need to tunnig this query. Wich table has indexes and what text have the view

Comment: How long does each query take separately?

Comment: We don't have a crystal ball... please provide execution plan

Comment: Wow. Not sure if `UNION` is the one to blame. And note, as was told before - union and union all provide different result.

Comment: UNION is like using DISTINCT, so there is a lot of sorting going on.  As has been suggested, tune each query to return distinct data and then use a UNION ALL.

Comment: In addition to query plan, you should also look into statistics io output, it should help you understand what's causing the slowness

Comment: @tobypls seperately they are taking 0sec , 1 sec , 0 sec .

Answer (score -4):

Use With(NoLock) after each of table name like,

```
Select * FROM smsFDGPatientOrder With(NoLock)
```

Alternate you can build non clustered index on columns, which are used in joins or selected in many of your queries. We have created indexes and queries giving us must faster results.

Comment: Transactions (almost certainly) aren't the underlying problem.

Comment: You'd be better off setting your isolation level to read uncommitted, if you are just going to add NOLOCK everywhere.  But then all your doing is a bunch of dirty reads, which may not be what you want at all.